# SurveyMonkey: Create New Query Type

Tags: surveymonkey

Is there a way to modify the type of survey questions that one can ask?

I'd like to have a simple form where a user inputs their date of birth, but the current Date/Time option requires me to have both a title and a question by the date field. I don't want to have both.

Comment: Have you considered a question of "When were you born?" with a label of "Date"?

Comment: Yes, ended up going with that. It just seemed unnecessarily wordy (mildly), because the format of the response already implied it's a date, but I guess I have to work with what there is. Thank you for your comment.